Donut oil absorption standards
What are the factors that affect the oil absorption during donut frying?  We are frying donuts daily and using too much shortening, so we need advice for reducing it. Are there general factors we should consider  to reduce oil or shortening use?

If your goal is to consume less oil or shortening then I would eat fried doughnuts less often, rather than trying to reduce the amount of oil in the doughnuts.

@dbmag9 my interpretation is that this is a question about donut production, perhaps the OP can clarify.

@moscafj I agree, the question is a fine one about making doughnuts, it's just that what the question asks isn't really the best way to achieve what the OP wants.

I'll take a stab at an edit.  If my edit is not what you intend, please say so.

A few things here: https://ifst.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1745-4549.2011.00611.x
